# Why isn’t wpa_supplicant working on Void Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, wifi, wpa-supplicant, void-linux

I installed a glibc Void Linux partition on my 2019 Macbook Air. I can’t get wpa_supplicant working.

I enabled wpa_supplicant and dhcpcd. Then I used wpa_passphrase with my Wi-fi network’s SSID and WPA2 password. I also added this to my wpa_supplicant.conf. Then I made a dhcpcd hook. The output of lspci —-nnk | grep Network is

“02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4355 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC [14e4:43dc] (rev 0c)”

and the output of ip link is

“1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UP mode Default group default qlen 100”.

Any ideas on what I did wrong?

Comment: You need a kernel >= 6.2.3 to get support for your device. What is your kernel version?

Comment: Thanks, seems like my kernel is outdated. I'll update this if this fixes it

Comment: Heh I'll make an answer about it then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [commit](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/?id=69005e67ce54cb837b8218b002c1bb868c83b7a9), in kernel 6.3 (and [backported](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/?h=linux-6.2.y&id=3ff7d7162d040bd821181f2da465e1ade9167e06) to >= 6.2.3 but not to any LTS 6.1.y including the latest 6.1.32) adds or finalizes support for BCM4355:

> wifi: brcmfmac: pcie: Add IDs/properties for BCM4355

[...]

> ```
> +#define BRCM_PCIE_4355_DEVICE_ID 0x43dc
> ```

So to ensure your NIC has a chance to appear in the interface list using `ip link` you must ensure you have a recent enough kernel.

Since it might not be backported to any LTS (eg: 6.1 series), to still get bug and security fixes you will probably have to switch to each newer kernel series at least until the next LTS in 2024.

Currently you should pick the [Linux 6.3 series](https://voidlinux.org/packages/?arch=x86_64&q=linux6.3).